# Spot error in proof: $A \times B=B \times A$ only if $A=B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets.

Here’s an incorrect proof that$A \times B=B \times A$ only if $A=B$: The first
coordinates of the ordered pairs in $A \times B$ come from $A$, and the first coordinates
of the ordered pairs in $B \times A$ come from $B$. But if $A \times B = B \times A$, then the
first coordinates in these two sets must be the same, so $A = B$.

Why is this proof incorrect?

Comment: To use the built-in LaTeX coding, use dollar signs.  A × B would best be typed $A \times B$. This also allows you to type set symbols like $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $$\bigcup_{k\in S}x_k$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is nonempty but $B$ is empty, then $A\times B = B\times A$, but $A\neq B$.

(The proof assumes that that $A\times B$ is nonempty, but this doesn't follow from the premises of the proof.)

Answer (score 0):

What the "proof" proved is:
$$\forall a,b[(a \in A \land b \in B) \iff (a \in B \land b \in A)]$$

And then tried to extrapolate it into:
$$\forall a[a \in A \iff a \in B]$$

This is the incorrect step.

(Note: the criterion of $A = B$ is $\forall a[a \in A \iff a \in B]$.)

Comment: it seems your approach is different from the textbook author and  Henning Makholm in the other post.  On page 167 http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf the author gives the flaw to be that we cannot necessarily find an b in B, i.e. B could be empty.  Compared to your approach which identifies the flaw to be distributing the universal over a implication.  If you could further elaborate on this issue that would be helpful.  As I said in the other post this is what confuses me,  since the other approach seems to treat a universal and make it into a existential.

Comment: Sorry to hassle you but can you comment on my comment please?  It would really help.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> The first coordinates of the ordered pairs in $A × B$ come from $A$.

it doesn't seem you're distinguishing sufficiently carefully between

1. The set of things that are first coordinates of something in $A\times B$ is a *subset of* $A$.
2. The set of things that are first coordinates of something in $A\times B$ is *the same set as* $A$.

The first of these is true, but it's the second one you would need for the rest of the proof to work. And the second is *not* true unless $B$ has an element.